# Why Indian credit cards don't ask for 3D Secure when transacting internationally?

Tags: credit-card, india, international, security, mastercard

I am from India and hold a credit card. While transacting in India, it always takes me to 3D Secure authentication page. But while paying in AliExpress, it never takes me to 3D Secure page, yet approves the payment.

Could anyone please explain why it happens or if I can enforce 3D Secure from my side by any means?

Comment: The business needs to support it, so unless you can make AliExpress change their process, your only options are to live without or not shop there.

Comment: Thnaks for the response @Aganju. Can my bank ensure that the payment is not approved if not verified by 3D Secure? Do they have the authority to?

Comment: It would be defined in your credit card contract, but pretty sure it is not there. Large parts of the world don't use 3D, so if your bank would enforce it, your card would be unusable for travel into most if the world.

Comment: @Aganju thanks a lot. [This is what I found out](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/80927/why-indian-credit-cards-dont-ask-for-3d-secure-when-transacting-internationally/80931#comment136791_80931)

Answer (score 2):

> Could anyone please explain why it happens

In general the approach banks take to managing card fraud on "card not present" payments is to make the merchant pay for it. The merchant then gets to decide on what extra security features to use and hence on the balance between user connivance, implementation complexity and fraud protection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just spoke to my bank. Turns out inside India, RBI, the central bank, enforces that every merchant has to use 2 factor auth. That is not the case with AliExpress as they're Chinese and RBI has no jurisdiction there. So only if my bank enforces it, it's possible, but it's private bank and security sort of takes a back seat to user convenience(!). So probably there's not much I can do.

Comment: The network decides on liability rules, not the bank. @Arumoy This isn't a matter of "jurisdiction". A bank can refuse to authorize a transaction regardless of where the merchant is.

Answer (score 0):

Card can be of two types,2d secure and 3d secure.So as payment gateways can be also 2d secure and 3d secure. If a 3d secure card goes through a 2d secure payment gateway it would not ask for otp. All Indian based payment service providers are 3d secure as per RBL mandate. but thats not the case with International payment gateways

Answer (score 0):

It's because the Reserve Bank of India (RBI) = India's Central Bank [mandated](https://rbi.org.in/Scripts/PublicationReportDetails.aspx?UrlPage=&ID=923) CNP transactions to use 3DS or similar in 2014.